# Can't remove view,edit,trash for custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove View, Edit, Trash for custom post type in WordPress and I have write function for this, but doesn't work for custom post type, only for Post

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
if( get_post_type() === 'map' )
    unset( $actions['edit'] );
    unset( $actions['view'] );
    unset( $actions['trash'] );
    unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of this problem is that you should replace post_row_actions with page_row_actions, and it work